# Low performance in non-sequential iteration over int Array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I have the following function:

```
public void scanText(char[] T){
    int q=0;
    for(int i=0;i<T.length;i++){
        q = transFunc[preCompRow[q]+T[i]];
        if(q==pattern.length){
            System.out.println("match found at position: "+(i-pattern.length+2));
        }
    }
}
```

This function scans a char Array searching for matches of a given pattern, which is stored as a finite automata. The transition function of the automata is stored in the variable called transFunc.

I am testing this function in a text with 8 millions of characters and using 800000 patterns. The thing is the accession of the array preCompRow[q] (which is an int[]) is very slow. The performance is greatly improved if I delete the preCompRow[q] of the code. I think this might be because in every loop the q variable has a different non-sequential value (2, 56, 18, 9 ..).

Is there any better way to access to an array in a non-sequential manner?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define "very slow".

Comment: I don't think that the java access to an array is the slow thing. ¿How is your ram? maybe you have all in ram and the OS is swapping a lot, so it goes to the disk to get your array position.

Try it with a few characters, to see the performance without using a lot of ram.

Comment: @Andreas I searched 4000 different patterns over a char array with 8324701 characters and it took **143** seconds. Then I run the same test but I change `transFunc[preCompRow[q]+T[i]]` for `transFunc[T[i]]` and it took only **9** seconds. @leoxs I didn't see any swap activity during the execution of both tests. I am using 2 GB for the heap

Comment: I you really need performance, you could code that in C and use it as a module in your java project.
If that can run in parallel, thinks about using threads, or better, doing that on GPU.

Comment: wait, T[i] returns a char, and then you sum it with preCompRow[q]. maybe the problem is not the array access, but that "+".
Don't make a benchmark with the full code, just try the access and the operation so you can find the bottleneck

Comment: I also thought the bottleneck was in +, but I tested several cases `transFunc[T[i]]`, `transFunc[1+T[I]]`, `transFunc[T[I]]` and all had reasonable performance, but every time I add preCompRow[q] inside the index the whole thing goes wrong. When I fix `q` to some value, things goes really fast, for example `transFunc[preCompRow[1]+T[I]]`. My conclusion was the problem was the value of `q` which in every pass of the loop can take a value between 1 - # characters of the pattern

Comment: I don't know the logic behind your code, but maybe you can sort the arrays in a way so you get more sequential values?

Comment: `System.out.println` takes time! When you change the logic from `transFunc[preCompRow[q]+T[i]]` to `transFunc[T[i]]`, we can only assume that will change the number of times `q==pattern.length`. Perhaps the difference is caused by a lot more printing. I mean, your code will iterate the same number of times, and I can't see that 2 vs 3 array lookups per iteration will make the difference between 9 and 143 seconds, so I'd say it has to be something different.

Comment: The problem is not the `System.out.println`, I forgot to mention I commented  this line for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is that your code is seeing poor memory performance due to poor locality in its memory access patterns.

The role of the memory caches in a modern computer is to deal with the speed mismatch between processor instruction times (less than 1 ns) and main memory (5 to 10 ns or more).  They work best when your code gets a cache hit most time it fetches from memory.

A modern Intel chipset caches memory in blocks of 64 bytes, and loads from main memory in burst mode.  (That corresponds to 16 `int` values.)  The L1 cache on (say) an I7 processor is 2MB.

If your application is able to access the data in a large array (roughly) sequentially, then 7 out of 8 accesses will be a cache hits.  If the access pattern is non-sequential and the "working set" of is a large multiple of the cache size, then you may end up with a cache miss on each memory access.

If memory access locality is the root of yoiur problems, then your option are limited:

- redesign your algorithm so that locality of memory references is better
- buy hardware with larger caches
- (maybe) redesign your algorithm to use GPUs or some other strategy to reduce the memory traffic

Recoding your existing in C or C++ may give a performance improvement, but the same memory locality problems will bite you there as well.

I am not aware of any tools that can be used to measure cache performance in Java applications.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. Since `T` values are `char`, they are likely limited to ASCII, i.e. within a numeric range of 32 and 126. `transFunc[T[i]]` will then only access those indexes of `transFunc`, and that entire range (760 bytes in total) will quickly be in the L1 cache. --- For `transFunc[preCompRow[q]+T[i]]`, we don't know range of `preCompRow` values, i.e. size of `transFunc`, but if that is large, it will take a lot longer to load it into L1 cache, and may even exceed size of `L1` cache, greatly increasing cache miss ratio, even for the same index values.

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is related to cache. `preComRow` is just an int array of the size of the pattern. Rows are precomputed because I am using a 2D array for the transition function but expressed as a 1D array (I thought I was having problem with JAVA 2D arrays emulation), then an array of the form arr[i][j] is expressed as arr[(I*steps) + j ], I precomputed this to avoid the computation in the searching loop. The thing is I know the range of `preCompRow`.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the patterns I am searching for are very short, only 50 characters long

Comment: It would help us if you created a MCVE for your problem so that we can observe and then diagnose the "slow accession" behavior.  Without a proper MCVE, I don't think it will be possible to do anything more than guess.